# How to calculate the data noise variance for a prediction interval?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, statistical-ai

I have a neural network that connects $N$ input variables to $M$ output variables (qoi). By default, neural networks just give out point estimations.

Now, I want to plot some of the quantity of interests and produce also a prediction interval. To calculate the model uncertainty, I use the bootstrap method.

$$\sigma_{model}^2=\frac{1}{B-1}\sum_{i=1}^B(\hat{y}_i^b-\hat{y}_i)^2\qquad \text{with}\quad\hat{y}_i = \frac{1}{B}\sum_{b=1}^B\hat{y}_i^b$$
$B$ training datasets are resampled from original dataset with replacement.  $\hat{y}_i^b$ is the preditcion of the $i$ sample generated by the $b$th bootstrap model.

If I understood it correctly, the model uncertainty (or epistemic uncertainty) is enough to create a confidence interval.

But for the PI I also need the irreducible error $\sigma_{noise,\epsilon}^2$. $$\sigma_y^2= \sigma_{model}^2+\sigma_{noise,\epsilon}^2$$

The aleatoric uncertainty is explained in the following picture:
[image]

Is there a procedure to calculate this aleatoric uncertainty?

I read the paper [High-Quality Prediction Intervals for Deep Learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.07167) and watched the corresponding  [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JWrE1EKbR_c&t=1116s). And I read the paper [Neural Network-Based Prediction Intervals](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5966350).

**EDIT**
I suggest the following algorithm to estimate the noise variance, but I am  not sure if this makes sense:

[image]